# Count the number of li's in a ul after some of the li's have had .remove() on them?

Tags: jquery

When you hit the delete button a nice effect is run on that li and it is removed by using jquery's .remove() function.
For some reason if i try to .size() on the parent ul it just still says the number of list items that were there when the page loaded?

*update*

```
var href = $(this).attr("href");
$(this).children(".deleteButton").fadeOut("fast");
$(this).parent("li").slideUp(300);
setTimeout("$(this).parent('li').remove();",300);
setTimeout("alert( $('ul.list').children().size());",300)
$.get(href);
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code

```
setTimeout("$(this).parent('li').remove();",300);`
```

is conceptually wrong.
You expect `$(this)` to be in closure but you are actually passing a string to the setTimeout callback.

So, when the callback is executed, `$(this)` refer to `window` (or document?? correct me plz)

You can put a callback to the `slideUp` function you call, so that you remove that element *after* the `slideUp` has terminated:

```
$(this).parent("li").slideUp(300,  function (){ $(this).remove();});
```

Answer (score 0):

SlideUp does not remove the element. It actually changes it's height and afterwards sets it's display to none.

Use a callback to remove the element.

```
$(this).parent("li").slideUp(300,  function (){ $(this).remove();});
```